# Can memory-mapped files be used for caching large data sets?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files, large-data

I have large data sets that must be loaded from files for UI display post data transformation.

Can memory-mapped files be used here as a buffer for storing these structures in a non-persisted way ? If yes, how much of a performance benefit can they provide?

Do memory-mapped files have an impact on memory usage by the application?

Thanks.

Comment: This might not be a good idea in .net, where the relationship between objects and  memory is indirect. In particular, garbage collection is free to move objects around in physical memory depending on whether or not they are referenced. This does not play well with the idea of allocating a particular area of (virtual) memory to a file. Why not use a database?

Comment: @TooTone: MSDN suggests that mapped files can be used in the same way as they are in unmanaged environment. From MSDN: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx) Starting with the .NET Framework 4, you can use managed code to access memory-mapped files in the same way that native Windows functions access memory-mapped files, as described in Managing Memory-Mapped Files in Win32 in the MSDN Library.

Comment: If your data in some easy to access flat-file format, like the array of structs in the MSDN example, you might want to consider memory mapped files, but, going back to the point that the association in .net between memory and objects is indirect, you don't have the ability you have in lower-level languages (e.g. C,C++) to map your objects directly onto the memory of the file, which is one of the major advantages of this approach.

Comment: Also, consider that the platform has it's impact on this. On Linux there are already POSIX functions that help you with this, while on Windows it's handled differently. If you don't take the platform into consideration you can't expect extreme benefits. And just keeping stuff in memory may mean it's faster than on disk, but how much depends on too many moving parts. Finding stuff (hashing/buckets/indexes) may have a relevance too.